# How to check if user is authenticated to navigate through Vue routes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, authentication, express-session

I'm creating a Single Page Application using Vue front-end, Express and Parse (parse-platform) for back-end. Whenever I authenticate user, I put user's info into session variable `req.session.user = result;` and then send it back to the client `res.status(200).send(req.session);`. Whenever user is routing through application, how do securely check if authentication is valid? What I am afraid of, is that the `session id` that is put into client's cookies could be forged and user would be treated as authenticated. I believe I could send a request to my back-end to check if authentication is valid every time user enters a route but I believe this is not a great idea as routing in vue applications are very quick and if hundreds of users navigating quickly could cause a problem. What else could I do? Or am I doing it/thinking of it the right way?

I use `express-session` to store client's session into his cookies.

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'secret_key',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {} }));
```

This is how I login user:

```
 Parse.User.logIn(username, password).then(result => {
     req.session.user = result;
     res.status(200).send(req.session);
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

first of all, I recommend using state rather than a session in a single page application.

vuex = https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

vue-router have a function called beforeEach.if we defined this function,it's called every time when we call a route. basically request go through this function.

then we can check this user is authenticated or not in this function

ex:-

```
let router = new Router({
  mode: "hash", // https://router.vuejs.org/api/#mode
  linkActiveClass: "active",
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: configRoutes(), // im using function to define all the routes. you can define routes here
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("userToken") == null) {
      next({
        path: "/login",
        params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath },
      });
    } else {
      if (!store.state.isAuthenticated) {
        next({
          path: "/login",
          params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath },
        });
      } else {
        next();
      }
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

after that, we define which route should be authenticated or not. Vue router allows us to define a meta on our routes so we can specify the authenticated routes

ex:-

```
{
   path: "/student",
   name: "student",
   component: Student,
   meta: {
         requiresAuth: true,
      },
 },
```

now everytime someone enter "/student" url it's gonna check if that user authenticated or not.

[this is where I learned this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vue-js-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router)

hope this will help someone.good luck

Comment: What prevents the user from adding userToken with some value to localstorage? Sure they may not see critical data, but they could still see the app UI?

Comment: @dataviews anything public like the web app should be considered insecure, which is why we don't expose secrets. The backend API should still authenticate. Although they could see more HTML, they can't do anything with it